# How to get possible ACL roles/rights on a folder using CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, localization, acl

I would like to know how to get the possible Rights on a folder using cmd ?

I will try to explain more my need so that you will understand my question :

I am using icacls to change ACL on MyFolder.

I am using a command like this one :

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyFolder" /grant:r Administrators:F
```

or

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyFolder" /grant:r Users:(OI)(CI)F /t /c
```

The problem is that if I run that on a french computer it's giving me an approbation error something like : "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed" ....

After making some tests I understood that the problem is that I am using Administrators and I had to use Administrateur (when running my script on a french Windows).

Same thing for "Users", I should use "Utilisateurs" and not "Users" in my command so that it works.

What I need is to know if there is a variable used by windows to help me for localization, to get automatically the roles using cmd, to replace "Administrators", "Users" by this variable, so that my code works on any Windows whatever is it's language...

What I need is something like :

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyFolder" /grant:r %Admin%:F


icacls "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyFolder" /grant:r %Users%:F
```

so that %Admin% will be replaced automatically by Administrators on an english computer and by Administrateur on a french computer and so on.

The complete syntax that I am using actually is :

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MYFOLDER" /grant:r Administrators:F /grant:r SYSTEM:F /grant Users:(OI)(CI)F /t /c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [well known SID string constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379602(v=vs.85).aspx)

```dos
icacls "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyFolder" /grant:r *BA:F
```

If the names are required for other uses, then you can ask WMI for the required information

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
        wmic    path WIN32_UserAccount
        where   ( 
                    LocalAccount^="True" 
                    And SID Like "S-1-5-21-%%-500"
                ^)
        get Name /value
    ') do for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%b in ("%%a") do set "adminName=%%b"

    echo Local administrator account = [%adminName%]


    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
        wmic    path WIN32_Group
        where   (
                    SID Like "S-1-5-32-544"
                ^)
        get     Name /value
    ') do for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%b in ("%%a") do set "adminGroup=%%b"

    echo Local administrators group  = [%adminGroup%]


    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
        wmic    path WIN32_Group
        where   (
                    SID Like "S-1-5-32-545"
                ^)
        get     Name /value
    ') do for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%b in ("%%a") do set "usersGroup=%%b"

    echo Local users group           = [%usersGroup%]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help....Any other way to get by cmd the value Administrator or Administrateur and put in a variable ? your answer may help in icacls example maybe, but it doesn't answer totally my question about if I can get the value of the role based on localization....
Do you have something equal to "BA" that allow me to do something like : echo %BA% and get "Administrator" on an english computer, and "Administrateur" on a french computer ?

Comment: Thanks a lot MC ND, I will try both method and let you know the result, I have also a need for system would you please add it to the script above ? it may help me and help others who will read one day your post.
By the way, were did you get the SID ? any microsoft link for that ? or it's based on your experience ? 

To make thinkgs Clear here is exactly the line that I am using, that's why I need admin, system and users 

icacls "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MYFOLDER" /grant:r Administrators:F /grant:r SYSTEM:F /grant Users:(OI)(CI)F /t /c

thanks again MC ND

Comment: @JustGreat, I've not seen any locale where you can not use `SYSTEM` to refer to the local system. Have you tried and got an error? You can run `wmic sysaccount where sid='S-1-5-18' get name,sid` to see the account name. The SIDs numbers are documented (ex. [KB243330](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330)) the same way that the SIDs strings.

Comment: The only one I tried and got the error was the whole syntax : 

icacls "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MYFOLDER" /grant:r Administrators:F /grant:r SYSTEM:F /grant Users:(OI)(CI)F /t /c

When I got the error and knew that it's related to the french version of windows, I knew that I have to change Administrator by Administrateur etc....I supposed that SYTEM should be replaced by SYSTEME also but I may be wrong because I haven't try SYSTEM alone....Will give it a try and let you know

Comment: @ MC ND, I just made the test and I confirm you that the problem was not SYSTEM, but users...System works on french Windows, but users doesn't work and should be replaced by Utilisateurs. Anyway thanks a lot for your help i will test both solutions you provide and let you know if all works now.